# Code getting stuck at JSON responsetext - Ajax cart

Tags: php, json, magento, jquery, prototypejs

I am trying to create ajax shopping cart and was succesful in adding the products with a single click on "add to cart" .but unable to update the Cart/header link without refreshing the page. Upon debugging, found out the code is getting stuck at "var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();" . I used alerts after and before json reponse text to debug.

Here is the code I am using for it:

```
var oldLabel;
            $$('.btn-cart').each( function(el){     
                oldLabel=el.select("span span")[0].innerHTML;
                el.title="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...'); ?>"; 
                el.select("span span")[0].innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...'); ?>"; });

            try {
                this.form.request({
                    parameters: { adeptaajax:'true' },    
                    onSuccess: function(transport){ 
                        var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                        var displayString = json.message;
                        if(json.success) {
                            $$('.block-cart').invoke('replace', json.cartsidebar);
                            $$('.header .links').invoke('replace', json.toplinks); 
                        }

                        $$('.btn-cart').each( function(el){ 
                            el.enable(); 
                            el.select("span span")[0].innerHTML=oldLabel; 
                            el.title=oldLabel; 
                        });
                        alert(displayString);
                    },
                    onFailure: function(transport){ 
                        $$('.btn-cart').each( function(el){ 
                            el.enable(); 
                            el.select("span span")[0].innerHTML=oldLabel; 
                            el.title=oldLabel;
                        });
                        alert("<?php echo $this->__('There has been a problem adding your product. Please try again later.'); ?>");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Debug it using FireBug, and watch the NET and CONSOLE tabs.

Comment: Sir!...Thank you very much ....You really made my day. If you were in front of me I would hug you with happiness :).

Comment: If you send `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before the JSON is output on the backend script the response is auto evaluated as JSON and is in `transport.responseJSON`

Comment: For others - found the error using Net-->Reponse Tab of Firebug. Error was at $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml(); ....I changed the name of top.links to top.links.custom earlier and forgot about it. Rectified it and all is working fine now.